# connect remotly to mysql server with php

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I can connect to mysql server with ssh .

```
# mysql -u username -h 185.2.3.80 -ppasword
```

output is :

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 280
Server version: 5.1.61 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

I want to connect to mysql server with php :

```
<?php
$servername = "185.2.3.80";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

this is output :

```
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '185.2.3.80' (13)
```

I turn off firewall with iptables and remove bind-address and skip-networking from my.cnf .but can not connect with php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.ssh can connect to mysql server but httpd can not connect mysql over network.I make httpd to can connect to mysql server over the network with :

```
 sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
<?php
$servername = "185.2.3.80:<server Port>";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

write your server port in my case it is 3306.
 Do one thing more go to your Cpanel -> remote mysql then add a percentage wild card to allow online access to your database.

Comment: I allow access from any host by removing bind-address.so i can connect with ssh.

Comment: did you try after adding port ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the database name.

First set your database name in a variable

```
$databaseName = '/* The name of your database */';
```

Try this :

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databaseName);
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: And following this guide ? https://technique.arscenic.org/lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php/mysql-le-serveur-de-bases-de/article/acces-distant-a-un-serveur-mysql